# Testing redux-saga

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am trying to implement a test for redux saga as follows but I ran into a problem. The error I get is cannot read property payload of undefined. The 'message' var that I passed to the saga function is undefined for some reason, can anyone tell me why? Thanks

```
  saga.spec.js
    import test from 'tape'
    import { put,take,call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
    import { onCreateMessage } from '../src/common/sagas/messages'
    import { addMessage,createMessage } from '../src/common/reducers/messages'


    test('createMessage', assert => {
        const gen = onCreateMessage()



        var message = {
            id: 1234,
            channelID: "AA",
            text: "text",
            user: "user"
          }

        assert.deepEqual(
            gen.next(message).value,
            put(addMessage(message)),
            'createMessage should dispatch addMessage action'
        )

    })

saga/index.js
export default function* rootSaga(){

    yield [ 

        takeEvery('CREATE_MESSAGE', onCreateMessage),
        ......
        ]
```

When I console logged message below I get 'undefined'

```
export function* onCreateMessage(message) {
    console.log(message)
    yield put(addMessage(message.payload))

    try {
        yield call(fetch,'/api/newmessage',
            {
             method: 'post',
             headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
             body: JSON.stringify(message.payload)}
            )

    } catch (error){
        throw error
    }
}
```

I am using actionCreator from redux-actions:

```
export const addMessage = createAction(ADD_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: you have to pass the arguments on the takeEvery... if not, use the take effect to yeild the first action into onCreateMessage, and you can get the value on message via an action.

Answer (score 3):

change

`const gen = onCreateMesaage()`

to

`const gen = onCreateMessage(message)`

Explanation:

`message` is the arguments passed to generator function rather than the `yield` result.
Previous code works for yielded result. e.g

```
export function* onCreateMessage() {
    const message = yield 
    console.log(message)
    yield put(addMessage(message.payload))
}
```